# javascript/jquery - How to take variable of child class name from repeated occurrences of parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT (old link to JSFiddle was wrong): Link to JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/uvexys0a/

I am attempting to program in jQuery so it wraps an HTML link to the staff member's profile page wraps around the entire each div with the class name `staffList`. The path to the page is stored as a child class in each div, as seen on the JSFiddle.

The code seems to function, somewhat. Both links end up going to John Smith's profile:

```
<a href="https://example.com/john-smith">
    <div class="staffList john-smith">
        <p>John Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="https://example.com/john-smith">
    <div class="staffList jane-smith">
        <p>Jane Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

However, if the code was running properly, it would output like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/john-smith">
    <div class="staffList john-smith">
        <p>John Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="https://example.com/jane-smith">
    <div class="staffList jane-smith">
        <p>Jane Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

How do you code so the variable `staffURL` changes with each repeated parent div with parent class `staffList` and the child class the corresponding staff member's link?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/yrc9o17n/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basing your links off of the second class name, but in your second staffList, you say John Smith again, so you get john-smith both times for each link. You can change that to jane-smith and loop over each item to get what you want. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var staffList = $(".staffList");
  
  $.each(staffList, function(i) {
    var staffURL = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    $(staffList[i]).wrap("<a href='https://example.com/"+staffURL+"/'></a>");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.staffList {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="warpper">
    <div id="staffSection">
      <div class="staffList john-smith">
        <p>John Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
      </div>
      <div class="staffList jane-smith">
        <p>Jane Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7nxbu1t5/2/

Comment: That was an old link and an error on my behalf. I edited the post to the new link (which is in regards to what you were saying) and it still only links john-smith.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvexys0a/

The loop you added to the jQuery helped.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to loop through each `staffList` item in order to set the URL dynamically.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  /**
   * Loop through each list item
   */
  $('.staffList').each(function() {
    var $listItem = $(this);

    var staffSlug = $listItem
      .attr('class') // Get the value of the class attribute
      .replace('staffList', '') // Remove the common class
      .trim(); // Clear up any pre/appending white space

    // Wrap element in `a` tag
    $listItem.wrap('<a href="https://example.com/' + staffSlug + '"></a>');
  });

});
```

```css
.staffList {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="warpper">
    <div id="staffSection">

      <div class="staffList john-smith">
        <p>John Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
      </div>

      <div class="staffList jane-smith">
        <p>Jane Smith</p>
        <p>Co-Founder</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer appears to work, however, for it to work I have to use the string split() method